# Assembly in Script Component through reflection works for random cases

Tags: c#, reflection, ssis, .net-assembly

I have a weird problem. I have a SSIS package with multiple DataFlows and within them I am using a Script component as a destination to write AVRO files. Now for writing these AVRO files, I am using Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.dll which I do not want to install to GAC and just refer using reflection. There is a cool guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/), which I have been following. Now all that worked in a demo project last week. However, today when I try to incorporate the same in my actual solution, some Dataflows work and everything goes fine but when the same script component is copied over to another dataflow and run using another dataset, it fails saying it can't find the assembly.

Point to note that - there is nothing wrong with the dataset, because the error is "loading the assembly".

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro, Version=1.1.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am at my wits end to find the reason for this as it is baffling.

Here is the code for reflection that I used and works in one dataflow and not in the other (within the same package)

```
    public ScriptMain()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    }
    public System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string path =  @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\" ; //@"D:\AVRO Serialize and Deserialize\C#\bin\Debug\";
        if (args.Name.Contains("Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro"))
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.dll"));
        }
        if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have copied the assembly in the DTS\binn folder as my posts have suggested.

How, do I see a log of which paths the SSIS runtime is looking at, when it runs? I do not know what more info I can give because this is really weird but if anyone wants me to put in more details, please let me know and I can edit the question to include more details.

P.S: I also added it to GAC one time and then it worked but I do not want to do that on the server and also the fact that reflection did work in another project

One more detail- last week when all dataflows worked in the test solution- It had the target version as 2017, which also showed up against the project name in Visual Studio. So, in the actual project where I have this weird problem of this working in one dataflow and not in the other, I tried to change the target server version to 2017 (from 2016), but the display against the project name still shows 2016. Could this be the problem? But then why does the display name of the project does not change to include 2017 even when change the target server version to 2017?

This is how it is in the solution where it all worked.

```
ProjectName (SQL Server 2017)
```

And this is how it is in the buggy project

```
ProjectName (SQL Server 2016)
```

Even changing the target version to 2017 does nothing to the display but I doubt this to be the problem

EDIT 1: OK, I seem to have figured out the problem. It is indeed the version. thee reason, why the display name was not changing to 2017, even though I had changed the target server version property to 2017, was because I didn't change it in the "Active(development)" configuration. I changed that, received some warnings from BIDS saying to backup etc etc. But after that, the same dataflow began to work, just like the previous project.

So, the question now is why does this piece of code works with SQL 2017 version of SSIS but not 2016. I understand from this post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d571848-e089-4d80-af1d-8800d0422354/not-able-to-find-dts-dlls?forum=sqlintegrationservices), that "In SQL Server 2017, the IS assemblies were upgraded to .NET 4.0", but this is not an IS native assembly.

Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally found the problem. Seems like SSIS target version 2016 and 2017 behave differently.

I had a List variable which I was initializing within the class right when it was defined and that was of course getting called before reflection had a chance to run.

So, getting down to the code, this is what it was

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    List<AvroRecord> CounterpartsRowList = new List<AvroRecord>(); //This line was the problem

    public ScriptMain()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    }
    public System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string path = @"D:\BDS\clientscoredata\ClientScoreDataSsis";
        if (args.Name.Contains("Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro"))
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.dll"));
        }
        if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
        }
        return null;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called once, before rows begin to be processed in the data flow.
    ///
    /// You can remove this method if you don't need to do anything here.
    /// </summary>
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        abc = new List<AvroRecord>(); // initialization moved here
```

So basically the the initialization of abc moved to the PreExecute method instead of right when it is defined.